# How to use values like 'From_Date' and 'To_Date'selected in Dot net page to Tableau page?

Tags: .net, sql-server, tableau-desktop

I have a VB.Net page for generating report. On this page user will select From Date, To Date and one value from the drop down list and after that user clicks on the 'Generate report' button on the VB.Net page for generating the report.

After user clicks the 'Generate report' button. Tableau should populate data from the database tables based on the condition user has selected on the VB. Net page like From Date, To Date and one value from the drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using tableau server, they allow URL parameters for filters and parameters.

https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/embed_structure.htm#adding-parameters-to-the-base-url

Generally you can just add ?Filter%20Name=ValueYouWant

See https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/embed_structure.htm#example-date-parameters on the same page as well for how to format the dates.

Comment: Thanks Matthew for your reply.  I am using Tableau Desktop. Are these features referred in your answer available in Tableau desktop?

Comment: Sorry, Dilip. As far as I know there is no way to do this in Tableau Desktop or Viewer. You need to use Server or Online for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I had another thought.

Although my first answer applies to Online or Server you might be able to achieve this with some VB.net wizardry.

Tableau workbooks are just xml files (or zipped xml). You could probably change the xml files and then open Tableau desktop.

[What Tableau API does InterWorks uses in their Workbook SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30136030/what-tableau-api-does-interworks-uses-in-their-workbook-sdk/30144958#30144958)